# Communicating with a Python service

Tags: python, winapi, command-line, service

**Problem:**

I have a python script that I have running as a service.  It's a subclass of the win32 class win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.  I want a simple straightforward way of sending arbitrary commands to it via the command line.

**What I've looked at:**

It looks like the standard way of controlling the service once it's started is by using another program and sending it command signals, but I need to be able to send a short string to it as well as an argument.  It looks like using a NamedPipe might be a good idea, but it's really too complex for what I wanted to do, is there any other simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

You have many, many ways to do "Interprocess Communication" (IPC) in Python.

- [Sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html)
- Named Pipes (see http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/named_pipes.html) -- it involves a little bit of OS magic to create, but then it's just a file that you read and write.
- Shared Memory (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) -- this also involves a fair amount of OS-level magic.
- Semphores and Locks; [files with locks](http://docs.python.org/library/posixfile.html) can work well for IPC.
- Higher-level protocols built on sockets...

  - HTTP; this is what WSGI is all about.
  - FTP
  - etc.

A common solution is to use HTTP and define "RESTful" commands.  Your service listens on port 80 for HTTP requests that contain arguments and parameters.  Look at [wsgiref](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html) for more information on this.

Comment: THanks.  This is sort of what my research came up with.  I think that I'm going to end up going with NamedPipes.

Comment: We use WSGI because -- overall -- it's very, very simple to implement with the wsgiref library.  Our clients use urllib2 to make requests.